# How to copy data from xlsx file to a text file

Tags: java, php, excel, xlsx, vba

How can I copy data from column A and B of an `xlsx` file to a text file using any of the following:

- Excel VBA script
- PHP
- Java

I am  on ubuntu 12.04.1, using Libreoffice for xlsx.

Also the words in the columns can have some special character like `(ü,ö,é,Ř)`, so the file can be ASCII only, and should be encoded in Unicode using the notation `\u + UTF-16` code point. Thus `“é”` becomes `“\u00e9”` and `“Ř”` becomes `“\u0158”`.

Comment: Since you are on ubuntu - is a shell script an option? Might be the quickest. 1 line should get you what you want.

Comment: @AnuragKapur ....could u please tell me how can I do that in shell script ?

Comment: I might have jumped the gun, but I think the following can work for you: 1. Convert xlsx to csv. 2. Use awk to copy the required columns to text file 3. Use iconv -f <from encoding> -t <to encoding> input.txt > output.txt

Comment: And the awk command example: cat input.csv | awk -F',' '{print $1 $2}' > output.txt to copy column 1 and 2 to text file

Answer (score 1):

For the Java case, you can use [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/index.html).

> jXLS is a small and easy-to-use Java library for writing Excel files using XLS templates and **reading data** [emphasis added] from Excel into Java objects using XML configuration.

Once you have loaded the Excel information  into a java object,  it will be easy to **export it to a text file** using any of the IO's java strategies.